# How to select mutiple rows from Entity using Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want write a LINQ query equivalent to

```sql
select * from Users 
where Username in ('something@somewhere.com', 'someone@somehting.com')
```

Is it possible to write this in LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to replicate the functionality of IN clauses you have to have (or create) a collection and check whether that collection contains the value you're looking for.

```
var search = new string[] {"something@somewhere.com", "someone@somehting.com"};

var results = Users.Where(u => search.Contains(u.Username));
```

Comment: Thanks D Stanley. This worked for me. Appreciate your quick input.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use a very lazy solution

```
 DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
 var users = db.Users.where(u => u.Username == "something@somewhere.com" || u.Username == "someone@somehting.com");
```

Very lazy (Easily understudy by beginner LINQ developer).

Comment: this solution is hard if you dont know the numbers of usernames to search for.